How to overcome Python3 installation Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding
While attempting to troubleshoot an issue on my Ubuntu for Windows installation I uninstalled all the python instances.  The issue has been resolved, but now I'm unable to get python3 reinstalled.
$ sudo apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3-stdlib python3-minimal python3.10
Suggested packages:
  python3-doc python3-tk python3-venv python3.10-venv python3.10-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3-stdlib python3 python3-minimal python3.10
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/562 kB of archives.
After this operation, 905 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1~22.04.6) ...
# Empty sitecustomize.py to avoid a dangling symlink
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  import site = 0
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fcf47778000 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.10-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm not certain, but I think this may be the core error:
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Any ideas?

There's something rather broken about the state of that machine. Since it's "just" a WSL install, I'd probably just reset the whole WSL state and start from scratch...

@AKX I already tried uninstalling the Ubuntu for Windows app from the Start menu and then reinstalling it from the Microsoft app store, but nothing changed.  How do I "reset the whole WSL state?"

See https://superuser.com/a/1755410/15580 for detailed instructions :)

Why not install Python 3.12.7 or Python 3.14.0a1?

@AKX Thanks for the link.  That resolved my issue.
